# Metric and topological structure in matrix Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am interested in a rather basic question, as I am studying Lie groups.

Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group, say $O(n)$. Consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{o}(n)$.

On the one hand, $\mathfrak{g}$ has some smooth structure (which I don't quite understand yet), and has some topology on it. 
On the other hand, $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a set of matrices and so it has a natural notion of a metric on it (say as the inherited metric as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$).

My questions are:

1. is the topology on $\mathfrak{g}$ compatible with some metric?
2. In particular, can I interpret the statement that $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ is a local diffeomorphism, as the fact that the restriction to some **ball** in $\mathfrak{g}$ around $0$ (rather than just a neighborhood) is a diffeomoprhism on its image?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "$\mathfrak{g}$ has some smooth structure"? It is just a vector space, it has the structure of $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d$ is the dimension. Do you mean $G$?

Comment: @CaptainLama I did mean $\mathfrak{g}$. What I really had in mind is not a smooth structure, but some notion that allows for a statement as "the exponential map is smooth" to make sense. I am unsure what this structure is.

Comment: I think the current answer addresses that. It is a finite-dimensional real vector space. A smooth structure is literally "looking locally like a finite-dimensional vector space". A map from $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a plain function with $d$ variables (where $d=\dim(\mathfrak{g})$), so the definition of smoothness is the classical one from basic calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on $\mathfrak g$ is the one induced by the distance that you will get from *any* norm that you define on $\mathfrak g$. Since $\dim\mathfrak g<\infty$, all those norms are equivalent (that is, they all induce the same topology). And, yes, what you wrote about the exponential map is correct.